# Angular2 innerHTML removes property, help needed to use DomSanitizer

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, angular-dom-sanitizer

I simply need to inject HTML in a div with `id` `"main-wrapper"`, so in my component.ts i am using this code

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef,Renderer2,Inject } from '@angular/core';
    import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
    import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-editsection',
      templateUrl: './editsection.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./editsection.component.css']
    })

    export class EditsectionComponent implements OnInit {
    ...//some code

    constructor(
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private elRef: ElementRef,
      private el: ElementRef,
      private _sanitizer:DomSanitizer
      ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    var strHTML = '<p>abc<p>';
     this.document.getElementById("main-wrapper").innerHTML += this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(strHTML);

    ...
    }
    }
```

**When i run the code it says:**
SafeValue must use [property]=binding:
abc

(see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

Why i need to implement this- Because when i am injecting innerHTML, i am loosing a property `contenteditable="true"`

**Before applying innerHTML, my code looks as shown below:**

```
<h1 _ngcontent-c2 contenteditable="true">Hii<h2>
```

**After applying innerHTML it becomes:**

```
<h1 _ngcontent-c2>Hii<h2>
```

Please help me resolve the problem

Answer (score 2):

The whole methodology behind angular is anchored on reduction of DOM manipulation via script (such as what you have) as recommended in http://angularjs.blogspot.com.au/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html.

> There are very few circumstances where manipulating the DOM directly is necessary.   Angular 2 provides a set of powerful, high-level APIs like queries that one can use instead.  Leveraging these APIs confers a few distinct advantages
>
> ...
>
> When you manipulate the DOM manually, you miss out on these advantages and ultimately end up writing less expressive code.

---

So instead of using this: `this.document.getElementById("main-wrapper").innerHTML +=`

You should make use of the templating engine /  structural directives like `*ngFor *ngIf` inherent in angular.

```
// .html
<div class="main-wrapper"><p *ngIf="showabc">abc</p></div>
// .ts
var showabc: Boolean = true;
```

---

**As per your comment:**

You are loading a bunch of html from localstorage. In this case, you will have to manipulate the DOM. Ideally i would recommend re-configuration of this architecture for performance purposes as stated in the aformentioned.

1st, load the html into typescript...

```
public possibleHTML: Array; 
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}
ngOnInit(){  
   this.possibleHTML = loadContentFromLocalStorage();
   this.possibleHTML = this.possibleHTML.map(value => this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value));
}
```

2nd insert the html.

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <content *ngIf="possibleHTML">
       <div *ngFor="let html of possibleHTML">
           <div *ngIf="html.makevisible" [innerHtml]="html"></div>
       </div>
    </content>
</div>
```

**drawbacks:** css styling does not take effect unless it is defined as a global stylesheet `styles.css` instead of `editsection.component.css`.

Comment: I just used a example `<p>abc<p>`. I have HTML code saved in local storage and depending upon user's selection that will be injected. So how do i go about that ? I was trying something like this `this.document.getElementById("main-wrapper").innerHTML += this.section_desc;  //injecting HTML HERE`

Comment: If i add like this `<div class="main-wrapper">{{section_desc}}</div>` then HTML does not take effect ,see this here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezw90ib6ncoxo4d/Screenshot%202017-06-14%2017.02.33.png?dl=0 , what do i do ?

Comment: @JessicaStorm Providing an example now for you - 5 mins please.

Comment: I am calling my css like this - ` <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/files/css/style.css">` , will it work ?

Comment: i am using  like this - `var strHTML = '<p>abc<p>';
this.possibleHTML = strHTML;`  and in html `<content *ngIf="possibleHTML">
           <div *ngIf="possibleHTML.makevisible" [innerHtml]="possibleHTML"></div>
    </content>`  but its not showing up the html content

Comment: @JessicaStorm if it is either on your `index.html` or included as an asset in your `angular-cli.json`

Comment: @JessicaStorm remove `*ngIf="possibleHTML.makevisible"` it was just an example incase you were passing an object.

Comment: Problem remain the same, if i am adding this property `var strHTML = '<p [contentEditable]="contentEditable" >abc<p>';` I am not able to edit in the injected html because this property is not coming on the DOM after injection

Comment: see this image - https://www.dropbox.com/s/y0puoolwief0a40/Screenshot%202017-06-15%2006.47.58.png?dl=0 , where as i coded `var strHTML = '<p [contentEditable]="contentEditable" >abc<p>';`  and my question is all about this

Comment: You can't `attribute bind` post manual injection @JessicaStorm http://ghost-imperativedesign.herokuapp.com/angular-2-property-and-attribute-binding-explained-in-depth/

Comment: The important part of that link is where they state that angular binds itself to attributes etc before the browser has parsed the html. this is why you see all the random angular bindings on elements such as `_ngcontent-qvx-7`, `_nghost-qvx-1` etc. I don't believe you can re-invoke this procedure.

Comment: i can pass `'<p class="content" >abc<p>';` and i can see this class, please provide me any way so that i can edit all texts which has `class=`content`

Comment: so DomSanitizer can be used here or can you think of any other idea of doing this ?

Comment: @JessicaStorm You would have to manually iterate the DOM and apply custom event listeners and attribute modifiers. I can't think of an elegant 'anglified' approach for what you are trying to achieve. I don't understand why you have to pull html from localStorage. This entire issue would be negated otherwise.

Comment: Why i need to pull html from local storage - Because my HTML editor fetches all sections from my server [Think app prespective, not online browser based solution]. If i add a new design to my server, then my existing users can fetch it and use it in their pages... Can you provide me a sample example of what you explained, it all went above my head..

Comment: @JessicaStorm I don't understand why you would do that over just providing them with the `html, css and ts` files, and then let them call the component in html? `<design [data-design-template-id]="2">` for example. Then that way you can have angular handle all this stuff for you? Make a module for each design template.. It just seems as though its rather overcomplicated - having the user download the data from a server, trust they put it in the correct location and then have it draw data at run time.

Comment: Also what about maintainability? What happens if one of the components has a bug. They hard inject the html via `innerHtml` then you will have to manually iterate all their files and strip out pre-existing html with the new stuff - instead of just being able to update 1 file which is then compiled.

Comment: i can show you over team viewer how my editor works in angular1 [mobile app] and i wish to do the same in angular2 , my html editor works offline on a mobile

Comment: jessica_storm1986 is my skype, if you can connect for 5 minutes, i will show you how my editor works on screen share

Comment: @JessicaStorm cool - I cant continue with this for about 4 hours unfortunately. I'll be back then.

Comment: Ok, i am looking forward to discuss this with you and do my next move, stopping this till we talk again