# Adding dynamic HTML from component to HTML is removing a property / attribute

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

I am trying to add html from `editpage.ts` to `editpage.html`

`editpage.ts`

```
var strHTML = '<p [contentEditable]="contentEditable" >abc<p>';
this.possibleHTML = strHTML;
 this.possibleHTML = this.possibleHTML.map(value => this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value));
```

`editpage.html`

```
<div  id="main-wrapper">   
    <content *ngIf="possibleHTML">
           <div [innerHtml]="possibleHTML"></div>
    </content>
</div>
```

When this is inserted, then in developer tools, it looks like this

```
<h1 _ngcontent-c2>Hii<h2>
```

My `[contentEditable]="contentEditable"` attribute is gone. I need to inject HTML dynamically and I need this attribute to change text.

### Edit

My `component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filemanager',
  templateUrl: './filemanager.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filemanager.component.css']
})
export class FilemanagerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
this.document.getElementById("main-wrapper").innerHTML += "<p [contentEditable]="contentEditable" >abc<p>";
  }

}
```

Now what I want is, my attribute should not be lost.

Comment: HTML added using `[innerHTML]="..."` is ignored by Angular. You won't ever be able to make Angular resolve value- or event-bindings or create component for content added this way. If you want Angular you process as string as template content dynamically, you can create a component at runtime and JIT-compile it.

Comment: below example is working

Comment: It doesn't add anything Angular-specific using `[innerHTML]="..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue myself not so long ago. The problem is with `contentEditable` that won't be added to your tags if you add it dynamically. If you want to add it, you have to use the `innerHTML` of a `HTMLElement`.

This means you can either use a `@ViewChild` decorator, or use JQuery to find your element. But it won't work by using Angular binding.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT** This is the example working in my project :

```
@ViewChild('itcamStr') itcamStr: ElementRef; 

// ... Doing other stuff in my component 

randomFunction() {
    // ... Doing stuff not related before
    this.itcamStr.nativeElement.innerHTML += this.buildLabel('string', 'type');
}

buildLabel(s: string, type: string): string {
    return `<label class="label label-${type} itcam-label" contenteditable="false">${s}</label>`;
}
```

**EDIT 2** Here is a fully working component :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my',
  template: '<div #child></div>',
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('child') child: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.child.nativeElement.innerHTML = `<p contenteditable>Editable Content</p>`;
    }
}
```

In your HTML page you juste have to do `<my></my>`.

Comment: can you provide an example which i can try, even by using innerHTML we are facing the same problem. My colleague posted this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556633/angular2-innerhtml-removes-property-help-needed-to-use-domsanitizer

Comment: Sure, please see my edit. I slightly changed my own code but you have a full working example here

Comment: I am new in angular and this looks like a bit complicated , i am editing my question after 5 minutes, can you adjust this code in my simple ts code please, will be helpful to test

Comment: Better, I will do another edit with a fully working component. Wait a second.

Comment: That thing worked but when i am trying like this - `this.child.nativeElement.innerHTML = `<p [contentEditable]="contentEditable">Editable Content</p>`;` this is not working, it actually works when i click the edit button which makes `[contenteditable]="true"` , any suggestion on this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146741/discussion-between-user2828442-and-trichetriche).

Comment: this is not working `this.child2.nativeElement.innerHTML = '<p contenteditable="${contentEditable}">Editable Content 2</p>';` my variable is `private contentEditable: boolean = false;`

Comment: Because you use simple quotes. You have to use the same quotes you use when you want to put in-line code in stack overflow. I'm not English so I don't know the name, but on an AZERTY keyboard you can find them by striking AltGr + 7.

Comment: This code has worked for me `this.child2.nativeElement.innerHTML = `<p contenteditable=${this.contentEditable}>Editable Content 2</p>`;`  but it is not changing the boolean on clicking a button, check out this video i have made for a better understanding of what is happening -  http://youtu.be/fiulSUg9Rgg?hd=1

Comment: No it's not, because as I told you in the chat, this has no relation with angular. If you want to make your contenteditable depending on a variable, you can't dynamically add it with html.

Comment: It is ok, i understand. Is there a way to fetch the data of <div #child></div> with all the elements having `contenteditable` attribute either removed or updated to `contenteditable="false"` , because when i'll export this code on an flat html file i dont want the text to be editable there.

Comment: Sure, you can use jquery or even native JS for that.

Comment: How can i use jquery or native js in angular2, can you point me to any tutorial or just simply include my js file as we do it normally ?

Comment: For the native JS, you can just write it in your component. Typescript is compiled to Javascript (if you don't know), so writing native JS isn't problem. About jquery, you have several ways. If you use angular CLI, you can install it with npm in the angular cli json file. If not, you can import it from a CDN in your index html file, but in both ways, in your Typescript file, you have to do `declare var $: any;` just under your imports.